# Android getting id of edittext from one xml to text view in other xml

Tags: android

I want to ask that is it possible that in xml 1 i hav a edit text and in another xml I have a button and  text view ..by clicking the button I want to get the edit text data from xml 1 which we write is showing in text view of xml 2
REMEMBER THERE ARE TWO XML ..plz let me know how it's possible

Answer (score 0):

If they are included (by using the tag include) in the same activity o fragment, you should be able to find them by using the findViewById as if they where the same.

If they are in different Fragments, you should use an interface to communicate them through the activity (two fragments should not communicate directly).

Anyhow, we need code, more details, and a more elaborated question to be able to help you properly.